# Vue is not defined in a standalone web component

Tags: vue.js, web-component

I am building a standalone Vue component and using it in another Vue project.

Build component:

```
vue build --target wc --inline-vue --name user-menu user-menu.vue
```

It's a simple component so far without functionality, just markup.

Then, in the main project in package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "user-menu": "git+https://........user-menu.git",
```

Then, in the main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import UserMenu from "user-menu"
....
Vue.use(UserMenu);
const app = new Vue(config).$mount("#root");
window.app = app;
Vue.use(UserMenu);
```

And it says:

> user-menu.js?e2ea:1446 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

on a row

```
module.exports = Vue;
```

But the [Vue CLI 3 documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) says that:

> In web component mode, Vue is externalized. This means the bundle will
> not bundle Vue even if your code imports Vue. The bundle will assume
> Vue is available on the host page as a global variable.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I think that a component bundled as web component cannot be used in vue project, try to build it as normal vue component using `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib [entry]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BoussadjraBrahim
Can you tell me how to use such library in the vue application? As usual "import .. form .." is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to the following solution: the component should not be built at all. Source files are enought to be imported like this:

```
import UserMenu from "user-menu/user-menu";
```

Pay attention that the path should point at the imported vue file, not just to the folder. But the extension "vue" must be skipped.
The final application will build it all together.